# Unable to upgrade to 13.04 from 12.10

Tags: 13.04, do-release-upgrade

When I open sortware update application I am not seeing any notification about a new release. So I tried to manually upgrade by running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 145, in <module>
fetcher.run_options += ["--mode=%s" % options.mode,
AttributeError: type object 'DistUpgradeFetcherCore' has no attribute 'run_options'
```

How do I upgrade to 13.04?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known and solved bug, reported here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1076186

You should now be able to upgrade by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Is there anything affected users can do to resolve the problem? Does it just work now?

Comment: It should work after running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`